# what is an alternative of azure availability set, azure disk external, azure network interface, azure resource group, in GCP

Tags: azure, google-cloud-platform, azure-devops, azure-functions

I need some help what is an alternative of azure availability set, azure disk external, azure network interface, azure resource group in GCP.

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to Resources Hierarchies, there is a different structure in Azure compared to GCP as you can see in the architecture below:

[image: AzureGCPAws]

According to this [article](https://endjin.com/blog/2016/11/aws-vs-azure-vs-google-cloud-platform-networking), most of the networking concepts like Network Interface are similar in both the Azure, AWS and the GCP. But some functionality and limitations are available to each service. Check the article given for more information.

When coming to managed disks in Azure, we have Persistent Disks and Local SSD in [Google cloud platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/gcp-professional/services#block-storage).

**Azure Availability Sets**:
For similar services in GCP and AWS, visit this [SO Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56630970/do-we-have-anything-similar-to-azure-availability-set-in-gcp-and-aws).

**References:**

1. [Resource Group/Resource Hierarchy of Azure vs AWS vs GCP](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/aws-azure-gcp-resource-hierarchies-25b829127511)